# Google NumberFormat With Pattern "Too many percent/permill"

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google chart's table chart and need to format some of the columns to decimal. When I try to use the `google.visualization.NumberFormat` to set the pattern to `#,##0.0%;(#,##0.0%)` I get an the `Uncaught Error: Too many percent/permill` error message.

I am on version 43 at the moment, and am unfortunately tied to using that version.

Here is a snippet of my formatter

```js
new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
     negativeColor: 'black',
     pattern: "#,##0.0%;(#,##0.0%)"
})
```

I save all of the column formatters in an array and then apply them to the table at the end. This is the line of code that is throwing the exception:

```js
columnFormatters.forEach(element => element.ColFormatter.format(dataTable, element.Ind));
```

I can use some of the other options to add the percent suffix, but I am also trying to let the table do the formatting of the data into a percent. I'd prefer not to have to do that on my end. Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: it doesn't work like Excel where you can define both positive and negative formats, accepts only one. try the first by itself --> `#,##0.0%`